# Count() inside linq query, how to avoid performance problems?

Tags: linq

I have this linq statement and I am facing some serious performance issues. I believe the problem lies in my .Count() invocations in the middle of the code.

```
var products = from product in pm_products
                       join price in GetResellers().Where(x => x.Price != 0) on product.Id equals price.PM_Price.Product_Id into productPrices
                       let minprice = productPrices.Min(x => x.Price)
                       let maxprice = productPrices.Max(x => x.Price)
                       let difference = ((double)maxprice - (double)minprice)/(double)minprice * 100
                       let number = productPrices.Count()
                       let success = productPrices.Where(x => x.Status == PriceStatus.OKAY).Count()
                       let unknown = productPrices.Where(x => x.Status == PriceStatus.NONE).Count()
                       let fail = productPrices.Where(x => x.Status == PriceStatus.FAIL).Count()
                       select new Product
                       {
                           PM_Product = product,
                           BestPrice = minprice,
                           WorstPrice = maxprice,
                           Fail = fail,
                           Number = number,
                           Success = success,
                           Unknown = unknown,
                           Difference = difference
                       };
```

I have read that Count() executes the query, but I only want it to execute once. How can I achieve that based on my construction above?

Comment: What happens if you remove `Count()`? Does your query become much faster?

Comment: Well, you're already aggregating the `productPrices` join at least two other times (min and max), so I doubt Count alone is responsible for it.

Comment: Yes. It goes from 1600 ms to 32ms

Comment: @Peter Have you tried moving your condition from the `Where` clause to inside the `Count` invocation? That is, remove `Where`, and do `productPrices.Count(x => x.Status == PriceStatus.OKAY)`. Does that improve anything?

Comment: @Asad I did what you suggested, but sadly no change in execution time

Answer (score -1):

You can bring basic collection and then do it in memory, and may be it'll help with the performance. Something like this:

```
let prodPrices = productPrices.Select(pp=>new {pp.Id, pp.Status})
```

then include it in your final `select` and you can get the counts from this in memory